# How to get parameters when they are defined in router.use?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This is Express 4.x. Let´s they I have following architecture:

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var mainRouter = express.Router();
var subRouter = express.Router();

subRouter.route('/').get(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.params);
});

mainRouter.use('/:username', subRouter);

app.use('/', mainRouter);
```

And then I call `GET /Amberlamps`. I would expect `req.params` being `{ username: 'Amberlamps' }`, but what I get is `{}`.

However, if I change my route in `subRouter` to:

```
subRouter.route('/:city').get(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.params);
});
```

And call `GET /Amberlamps/Berlin`, `req.params` is `{ city: 'Berlin' }`.

**How do I get `:username`?**

**EDIT:** Upon request I would like to explain, why I want to use a router as `subRouter`.

Let´s say I want to build a RESTful api server with following architecture:

`[path_to_api_server]/[version]/[resource]`
`http//api.example.com/1/users`

**server.js**

```
mainRouter.use('/:version/items', itemsRouter);
mainRouter.use('/:version/messages', messagesRouter);
mainRouter.use('/:version/users', usersRouter);

app.use('/', mainRouter);
```

**usersRouter.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var usersRouter = express.Router();

usersRouter.route('/')
  .get(getUser)
  .post(postUser)
  .put(putUser)
  .delete(deleteUser);

module.exports = usersRouter;
```

The beauty of this is that every resource router works without even needing to know on which path it is listening. The resource routers however need to know the version number defined in `:version` as functionality might differ.

Comment: Your `subRouter` is encapsulated inside the `mainRouter`, it doesn't know about it - in your case, you shouldn't use a subrouter if you wanna know about `:username` - maybe if you specify why you need a subrouter, i could help you more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an answer for you that may fit to your needs. As the subRouter is encapsulated by the mainRouter, so doesn't have access to `version`, add a middleware that will pass the version from the main to the subRouter.

```
var express = require('express');
var mainRouter = express.Router();
var subRouter = express.Router();

var app = express();

var apiRoutes = {
    itemRouter : function(req, res, next){
        console.log('/items','version',req.version,req.params);
        next();
    },
    messagesRouter : function(req, res, next){
        console.log('/messages','version',req.version,req.params);
        next();
    },
    usersRouter : function(req, res, next){
        console.log('/users','version',req.version,req.params);
        next();
    }
}

subRouter.route('/items/:id').get(apiRoutes.itemRouter);
subRouter.route('/messages/:id').get(apiRoutes.messagesRouter);
subRouter.route('/users/:id').get(apiRoutes.usersRouter);

//attach a middleware that will pass through the version to the subrouter via the request object
mainRouter.use('/:version', function(req, res, next){
    console.log('version', req.params.version);
    req.version = req.params.version;//pass version via req object
    next();
});

//attach your subRouter
mainRouter.use('/:version',subRouter)

app.use('/', mainRouter);

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There are a lot of workarounds for my problem. I just needed an answer to my specific problem, whether it is generally possible to get `:version` using my proposed architecture. I am guessing the answer is not?

Comment: This way, you can access version in your subRouter, and even check it in the mainRouter (if it is valid) before passing to the subRouter (you could return http status 400, if some is trying something like `/dsf/users/12` instead of `/v1/users/12`

Comment: It is still not what I want. You are using `subRouter.route('/users').get(usersRoute);`. But I want to have `mainRouter.use('/users', usersRouter);`.

Comment: I tried your idea, modified it a little bit and now it works exactly how I wanted it to work. Thanks!